# How to enable axis in chrome developer tools?

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox, google-chrome-devtools

I tried to enable the axis guides in inspect mode, but unfortunately I can't see any options to do that. How can I enable the axis tool?

[image: chrome axis tool]

Comment: Where did you see/read that such axis tools should exist?

Comment: I saw it on paid course video about flexbox where a guy was describing how axes are working, but did not told how to enable this tool.

Comment: Have you reached out to the course author to ask about the tool? They could have their own browser addon that is affecting this, or it could be added during video editing.